# Copy column from one table to another, ignoring duplicates

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Table 1: Words

```
__________________________________________________________________________
| word_id | word | category_title |             definition               |
|---------|------|----------------|--------------------------------------|
|    1    | cat  |    animals     |    a four-legged feline creature     |   
|    2    | bob  | famous people  |    a very famous reggae artist       |
|    3    | dog  |    animals     | a four_legged hound, enemy of feline |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Table 2: Categories

```
________________________________________________
| category_id | category_title |     imguri     | 
|-------------|----------------|----------------|
|      1      |     animals    | animals_banner |
|      2      | famous people  | fms_ppl_banner |
-------------------------------------------------
```

My code:

```
public class MyDBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Memoplay.db";

    public static final String TABLE_NAME_WORDS = "words";
    public static final String COLUMN_WORD_ID = "word_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_WORD = "word";
    public static final String COLUMN_CATEGORY = "categorytitle";
    public static final String COLUMN_DEFINITION = "definiton";


    public static final String TABLE_NAME_CATEGORIES = "categories";
    public static final String COLUMN_CATEGORY_ID = "category_id";
    //public static final String COLUMN_CATEGORY = "categorytitle";
    public static final String COLUMN_IMGURI = "imguri";

    //constuctor method
    public MyDBHandler(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String createWordsTableQuery = "CREATE TABLE" +
                TABLE_NAME_WORDS + "(" +
                COLUMN_WORD_ID + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
                COLUMN_WORD + "TEXT," +
                COLUMN_DEFINITION + "TEXT," +
                COLUMN_CATEGORY + "TEXT" + ");";
        db.execSQL(createWordsTableQuery);

        String createCategoriesTable = "CREATE TABLE" +
                TABLE_NAME_CATEGORIES + "(" +
                COLUMN_CATEGORY_ID + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT" +
                COLUMN_CATEGORY + "TEXT" +
                COLUMN_IMGURI + "TEXT" + ");";
        db.execSQL(createCategoriesTable);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
}
```

My aim:

I would like to generate a table for the unique categories found in the words table, I know there are similar answers on stackOverflow for copying columns to a new table however none of them (that I could find) addressed how to associate new data such as the 'img uri' and a unique primary key with each of the copied values.

I am pretty new to sqlite and android any help would be greatly appreciated
Thanks.

Comment: Repeating the `category_title` in both tables isn't the proper way to design your database. You should use the `category_id` column and **JOIN** your tables. This is called **normalization** and it is a key concept in relational databases.

Comment: @Rotwang Thanks for the comment, I have looked up the JOIN clause but have only found uses for it when both tables are populated, what I am trying to do is generate the 2nd table from the unique categories listed in the first table, so that I may  associate a imgUri and an ID with each unique 'category' currently the categories table is empty (unpopulated) so I don't know if the join clause will work however If there is a way to do this with the JOIN clause i would very much appreciate a reply to your comment.

Thanks

Comment: It simply doesn't seem a reasonable logic, to me.

Comment: @Rotwang The reason I've chosen to do it this way is because the data in Table 1 : 'words' will be submitted by the user, the categories they specify will not be known to me beforehand, from the records in Table 1 I then want to gather all of the unique categories, to better sort the information provided by the user (into distinct categories)

 [link](http://imgur.com/a/JfLnt)
This Image should be better at explaining, why I want to generate the categories, each category is converted into a card view, that contains all of the words found within that category.

Comment: You should provide a way to add a category, with its autogenerated id. Then the users can input whichever word and associate it with the new category. But the category must exist first.

Comment: @Rotwang Okay I will try this, Thanks